# Get files and directories name from "ls -l" command

Tags: java, string

I'm using Jsch library to make some operation on servers via SSH protocol. One of those operation requires to get the files and directories name from the output of "ls -l" bash command.

I tried to analyze the string in this way, but it's quite awful:

```
private static final int STRING_CUT_POINT = 46;

   String s = pName.substring(STRING_CUT_POINT);
   if (s.length() > 0) {
       int i = 0;
       while (s.charAt(0) != ' ') {
           s = pName.substring(STRING_CUT_POINT + i);
           i++;
       }
       this.name = s.trim();
       if (pName.charAt(0) == 'd') {
       this.type = DIRECTORY;
   } else {
       this.type = this.getFileType(this.name);
      ...
```

With that, on an output like this...

`drwxr-xr-x   2 mattia mattia   4096 22 mag 11.53  Desktop`

I can get "Desktop" but, for example, if owner name is shorter, the output will be "11.53 Desktop".
I also tried with `string.lastIndexof(' ')`, but it wouldn't work with a file/dir that contain white space into the name.
Any idea?

Comment: you can use regex pattern and some arguments in `ls`to remove some of the fields you don't need. Note that each field is separated by space, maybe you can also use `split`

Comment: Use string split to split the string into an array using space as a delimiter.

Comment: If a file/dir contain a white space? For example "a b.txt", if I split the entire output it will be cutted in two string "a" and "b.txt".

Comment: "it's quite awful" yes, parsing the output of ls is strongly advised against (see [here](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)). Is using `ls` a strong requirement, or could alternatives be proposed?

Comment: @MattiaB think smart, if the name is the last field and you know how many fields there are, you can limit the output size of `split`

Comment: @jhamon thank's a lot!

Comment: I am just wondering: JSched also supports the file transfer. Maybe it could be easier to use that functionality to read a list of files?

Comment: As an alternative, use `stat --format=<format> <file> ...` with a format string that is easy to parse.

Comment: @KonradNeitzel It's not necessary, i just want to know the files and directories into a specific path. So ls is quicker.

Comment: When I do ls -l on my box, everything up to the file/directory name is fixed width, so (as in your example) one could simply ignore the first 50 characters (or start on the 51st if you prefer to look at it that way.)

Comment: @Duston On mine start at 47, on my Raspberry starts at 40, on my server start at 50. It's not a standard. Anyway, as jhamon suggested, this is how i handled it:
`String[] s = pName.split("\\s+");
        if (s.length > SPLIT_POSITION) {
            this.name = "";
            for (int i = SPLIT_POSITION; i < s.length; i++) {
                name = name + s[i];
            }`

Comment: you could have used [split(string,int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)) to avoid writing the concatenating loop